# SQL command to run a report on Customers in Database

Tags: sql

I have to run a report on Customers in Database showing Names, State, and Phone Numbers. I have the commands but I keep getting a syntax error in the Select statement. Here's what I have so far. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
SELECT (Last Name, First Name, State/Province, Business Phone)
FROM Customers
VALUES ('Cross', 'Sandra')
VALUES ('Speight', 'John')
VALUES ('Powell', 'Bill')
VALUES ('Stolle', 'Ryan')
VALUES ('Newman', 'Tony')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with Sandra Cross, John Speight etc? What are the fields in your customers table? Are you trying to get lastname, firstname, state/province, businessphone of all customers or only those of the 5 people mentioned in your query?

Comment: You wana select OR insert ... That is half-and-half

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the lastname, firstname, state/province, business phone only for those 5 people.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT [Last Name]
    ,[First Name]
    ,[State/Province]
    ,[Business Phone]
FROM Customers
WHERE [First Name] IN (
        'Cross'
        ,'Sandra'
        ,'Speight'
        ,'John'
        ,'Powell'
        ,'Bill'
        ,'Stolle'
        ,'Ryan'
        ,'Newman'
        ,'Tony'
        )
```

Comment: Ideally you would not have spaces in column names. instead use _ i.e. Last_Name or lastName you can then change the column name on the select like - SELECT [lastName] as 'Last Name',

Comment: Glad I could help, could you please up vote this answer?

Comment: Square bracket delimiting is product specific (and no dbms is specified in the question.) ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. "First Name", will work with MS SQL Server too.